# Embedding Dynamic HTML table in email from Unix shell

Tags: html, css, bash, shell, unix

I want to read a csv and create a dynamic HTML table through UNIX shell. Number of rows and columns in csv could vary every month, hence wanted a dynamic table. The code that i have shown here creates table, but the table header is not appearing bold. Since CSS doesn't work with emails, am unable to achieve first-child attribute.

The code that i have shown here creates table, but the table header is not appearing bold. Since CSS doesn't work with emails, am unable to achieve first-child attribute.

```
awk 'BEGIN{
FS=","
#print  "MIME-Version: 1.0"
#print  "Content-Type: text/html"
#print  "Content-Disposition: inline"
print  "<HTML>""<HEAD>"
print "<STYLE>"
print "TR:first-child {font-weight: bold;background-color: grey;}"
print "</STYLE>""</HEAD>"
print "<TABLE border="1">"
}
{
printf "<TR>"
for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
printf "<TD>%s</TD>", $i
print "</TR>"
}
END{
print "</TABLE></BODY></HTML>"
}
' /home/test.csv  > /home/test_file.html
```

Expected table output in the email:

```
Job name | Date     | Status
----------------------------- 
Job 1    | 08/08/19 | Success    
Job 2    | 08/09/19 | Failure    
Job 3    | 08/10/19 | Success
```

Comment: The first child of `TR` is `TD` so your style applies to first TD and not first table row.

Comment: Thanks ! Could you tell me how i can achieve the expected output? What should be the first-child ?

Comment: @Vivek: BTW, your code will fail if the CSV contains fields with embedded newlines or commas, for instance `FIELD1,"FIELD2,more in FIELD2", FIELD3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Default, HTML recognises table heads `TH` and emboldens them. This also applies to emails. You want to adjust your code to use `TH` for the header row, and `TD`s for subsequent rows. See sample below;

```
# Top part of your code goes here to handle the headers...
{
    printf "<TR>"
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        printf "<TH>%s</TH>", $i
    print "</TR>"
}
# Rest of your code goes here, including subsequent rows using <TD>
```

Should you wish to style the headers, you can use the `TH` selector like so;

```
<style>
    TH {
        background-color:gray;
        /* Other styles */
    }
</style>
```